# More detailed explanation of a range tree, maybe with c++ implementation?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to learn more data structures for programming contests. I've looked at/implemented a segment tree, but a lot of solutions on topcoder/other forums references a "range tree". None of these solutions go in depth on what they're doing, or how a "range tree" works (specifically 2-Dimensional). The only relatively useful link I've found is (http://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cot5520fa09/CG_RangeTrees.pdf) but it appears to be really broad.

A lot of the example code is terse because it was coded in a contest environment, and likewise the library code is hard to read because of templates, among others?

Could anyone give a concise explanation of a 2-d range tree? (e.g. How to store/represent it, functionality, etc).

From my readings I understand that it can pretty much store any aggregate characteristic about a range, like a segment tree (?)

Thanks

Comment: Ordered Tree?  I'd think Wikipedia is actually a good place to start.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree  They have such nice pictures.  They have everything even comprehensive list of [traversal / search algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).  Code, animated GIFs, etc.

Comment: Does searching on 'KD tree' yield better results and is that even the same thing?  I get some of these confused.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @ficuscr I have that same problem too, the range tree seems ambiguous, and people seem to arbitrarily refer to it as a segment tree, among other names.

Comment: This might be confusing, Range Tree hold the ranges, real data is mapped to relative points

Answer (score 0):

I'll lead you to lecture 3 in http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/lectures/